# Como fazer select de 2 id para trazer Nome Diferente

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Estou com problema para efetuar um SELECT no `Postgres`, da seguinte forma.

```
Tabela -> Pessoa
```

Nessa tabela, são armazenados dados de Clientes, fornecedores, Exportadores, Fabricante, Não existe uma tabela para cada tipo de "Pessoa".

Em outra tabela chamada Processo, eu tenho `idexportador` e `idfabricante`, porém quando vou fazer um `SELECT`, como vou trazer o nome em vez dos `ids`?

Observem que na tabela pessoa tem a coluna `nmpessoa`, como faço para trazer o nome tanto do Exportador como DO fabricante?

Segue minha Query:

```
select
nrprocesso, nmpessoa as Exportador, txdescricaomercadoria
from
processo
inner join
diitem
on
processo.idprocesso = diitem.idprocesso
FULL OUTER JOIN
PESSOA
ON
diitem.idexportador = pessoa.idpessoa
where
idpessoacliente in (select idpessoa from pessoa where nmpessoa ilike '%KULZER%')
/*txdescricaomercadoria ilike '%L5005%'*/
AND
DTABERTURA >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY
txdescricaomercadoria
```

Comment: vc precisa realizar o `join` duas vezes na tabela pessoa referenciando a tabela duas vezes, ou seja vc vai repetir `pessoa` uma vez para o id do exportador e outra para o id do  fabricante

Comment: A tabela Pessoa participará da query com vários papéis: Cliente, Fornecedor, Exportador e Fabricante. Algo do tipo `INNER JOIN pessoa cli ON (diitem.idcliente = cli.idpessoa)
INNER JOIN pessoa exp ON (diitem.idexportador = exp.idpessoa)
INNER JOIN pessoa for ON (diitem.idfornecedor = for.idpessoa)
INNER JOIN pessoa fab ON (diitem.idfabricante = fab.idpessoa)`

Comment: Não entendi o que pretende com este FULL OUTER JOIN. Não me parece fazer sentido para sua descrição do resultado desejado.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, consegui executar a query, realizando a referência exp. pessoa.
Utilizei o Full, pois eu também preciso de resultados que não contenha Exportador ou fabricante preenchido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo assim (como disse o @JMSlasher

```
select
nrprocesso, exp.nmpessoa as Exportador, 
imp.nmpessoa as importador, txdescricaomercadoria
from
processo
inner join
diitem
on
processo.idprocesso = diitem.idprocesso
FULL OUTER JOIN
PESSOA EXP
ON
diitem.idexportador = EXP.idpessoa
FULL OUTER JOIN
PESSOA IMP
ON
diitem.idimportador = IMP.idpessoa
where
idpessoacliente in (select idpessoa from pessoa where nmpessoa ilike '%KULZER%')
/*txdescricaomercadoria ilike '%L5005%'*/
AND
DTABERTURA >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY
txdescricaomercadoria
```